# Azure Devops Build Installer Projects (MSI) suddenly not working anymore

Tags: azure, azure-devops, windows-installer

Since this morning I get this vague error on my Azure Devops. The log file isn't there and it used to work perfectly. It build automatically during the days and I have no problems creating the MSI.. I tried to set the debug = true in Azure Devops but can't see anything more.

Any ideas?

> Unable to process command '##vso[task.addattachment
> type=Distributedtask.Core.Summary;name=Installer project
> errors;]C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\VS
> Agent_work\1\b\BuildInstaller_Log_20190620151007.txt' successfully.
> Please reference documentation
> (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
>
> Cannot upload task
> attachment file, attachment file location is not specified or
> attachment file not exist on disk An error occurred while running
>
> DevEnv! Please review logfile BuildInstaller_Log_20190620151007.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio license was expired on the build server. This caused this awkward error message. Runs fine now

Comment: How do you fix an expired license when you're using Azure's hosted pipelines?

Comment: @AaronC.deBruyn In my case I just logged in on my virtual machine where the pipeline was running on, opened Visual Studio, logged in with my account and it was working again!

Comment: Maybe I'm just an Azure noob, but the service I'm using appears to be fully managed.  The images are provided and managed by Microsoft automatically.  I'll keep digging. :)

Comment: @AaronC.deBruyn, then the license can't be expired if you use the managed services from Azure itself.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking...so I filed a report with Microsoft because their system apparently doesn't collect that BuildInstaller_Log file.  They confirmed it's a bug and are investigating.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is generated in the PowerShell script for the BuildTask (DutchWorkz BuildInstaller 1.2.4 in our case) which you can inspect if you have access to the build agent. The error occurs because the log file, in your case  "BuildInstaller_Log_20190620151007.txt" did not exist. It is a secondary error that masks the real error, which is that devenv refused to run and so did not even generate a logfile. In our case, it wrote the message "The license for Visual Studio has expired...." and some more to stdout (not stderr).

The DutchWorkz BuildInstaller buildTask captures the stdout and writes it to the console in its debug output.

To see the debug output, set the build variable "System.Debug" to true: Your Azure Devops page -> Pipelines -> Select the pipeline you are interested in -> Run Pipeline -> Variables -> System.Debug -> true -> Update -> back -> Run. Alternatively, Your Azure Devops page -> Pipelines -> Select the pipeline you are interested in -> Run Pipeline -> Enable Diagnostic Output -> Run.

The fix for the "license expired" issue  is generally to log into the machine where the pipeline runs (virtual or not) as the user that runs the pipeline, run devenv interactively and enter the credentials again when it asks. Visual Studio Community may require you to do this from time to time; in our case, it seems to want renewal of the license every year.

People otherwise get the error

```
Unable to process command '##vso[task.addattachment type=Distributedtask.Core.Summary;name=<some name>;] <path>\<someFile.ext>' successfully
```

and in that case, the error is already obvious in this very output: There is  a blank space before <path>\<someFile.ext>, and PowerShell does not like that. But in that case, the build task is written badly and its powershell script is wrong, the blank should be omitted.